# SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

Can you please help me know what maybe the error in my sql?
I'm having missing expression error but I cannot find the error.
Thank you very much in advance.

```
SELECT SYSTEMNAME, round(MAX(GBL_CPU_TOTAL_UTIL),2) AS AVE_CPU,
convert(varchar(20),DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DATETIME), 0),110) AS DATE
FROM dbo.[GLOBAL]
WHERE (SYSTEMNAME IN ( 'X1','X2','X3'))    
AND (DATETIME > DATEADD(month, - 24, GETDATE()))
AND (DATETIME BETWEEN '12-27-2011 00:00' AND '12-30-2011 00:00')
GROUP BY SYSTEMNAME, convert(varchar(20),
DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DATETIME), 0),110)
ORDER BY DATE
```

Error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 9
```

Comment: Use quote for DATE field > order by "DATE";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convert(varchar(20), ...` ?

As far as I know, `convert` is used to convert a string from one character set to another. `varchar(20)` is *not* a string. This is also likely to be the case since that "line 2, column 9" is exactly where the `varchar(20)` is.

The doco for `convert` states:

---

**`convert( string1 , char_set_to , [ char_set_from ] )`**
`string1 is the string to be converted.`
`char_set_to is the character set to convert to.`
`char_set_from is the character set to convert from.`

---

If your intent is to cast the date difference to a `varchar(20)` type, you should probably be using `cast`.

Comment: That SQL is odd..really odd. Most of the functions, the `dbo` all point at T-SQL.  Looks like the SQL has been blind copy+pasted from a SQL Server query